# Importance of optimization

Tags: c#

How important is to keep your code optimized up to a tiny detail nowdays, especially if you build a small/medium applications?

Is it really that noticeable in performance, or just a matter of writing a good code and training yourself to be on the top level, no matter what task do need to achieve?

I'm asking about trivial examples such as using `StringBuilder` instead of simple string concatenation

```
StingBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("string1");
sb.Append(" string2");
```

vs

```
string s = "string1"+" string2";
```

using `Int16` vs `Int32` when situation allows it,

or  using

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){"string 1", "string 2"};
```

vs

```
string[] list = new string[2]{"string 1", "string 2"};
```

Those are just trivial examples, but I would like to know, did any of you had a case where those tiny optimizations had a noticeable impact in application performance?

Comment: Sometimes it's important. Sometimes it's not important. It depends on your context. With no other context, this question is too broad. A piece of code which isn't a bottleneck in one place may well be a bottleneck somewhere else.

Comment: `for` loop always faster than `foreach` loop. You can simply use `for` instead of `foreach`

Comment: Pretty important, it is the only way you are going to find out that writing code like this is pointless since the compiler already knows how to concatenate strings efficiently.  But of course you actually have to *verify* that or you still haven't learned anything.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil, like someone said. First write good maintainable code, and then optimize if necessary. It may be easier to optimize later, when you have a well structured code.

Comment: @Kowalski But for loop is not always the better choice, since it leaves the item instance mutable.

Comment: Thank you all. Even tho, my question was not direct, answers and comments helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizations depend on your actual domain. Simple good coding practices are never a waste of time, but anyway, you shouldn't blindly-optimize your code because you think that certain practices may increase your overall application performance.

You should take advantage of profilers to watch memory consumption, CPU usage and other indicators, and develop a good development environment to perform load tests. This way, you'll be able to determine your application's bottlenecks.

I always say that it's more important to start with a good software architecture rather than with an optimized code base, because a good software architecture is easy to refactor or just re-implement its black boxes with better code, but a wrong software architecture is simply a bunch of spaguetti code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this entirely depends on your context. If your app just concatenates two strings and that´s it (to be on your example), I doubt there is a huge effect on using one over the other. However repreading such a few thousand or million times can lead to even a simple int-calculation a huge bottleneck.

Anyway, [beware of optimization](http://www.clean-code-developer.com/Beware-of-Optimizations.ashx). You should instead consider code that is readable and maintainable.